# unix join not working: file is not sorted (and they are!!!)

Tags: sorting, unix, join

I have been trying to do a unix join but it doesn't seem to work. I have two files, they are both sorted, the first column on both is a number.

The problem seems to be in the order in which the join is being executed (and how it reads the attribute).

The error output is:

```
join: tags.csv:34: is not sorted: 109,1219,Alfred,Hitchcock,1165555288
join: users.csv:800: is not sorted: 10,F,35,1,95370,1009,5,979168267
```

So I have a 109 value in the line 34 of the tags file and a 10 value in the 800th line of users file. So, it seems to be comparing 10 vs 109 (like trimming) but it gives a error saying it's not sorted.

I have tried changing the order of the files in the join execution, but no luck.

Has anyone experienced something like this?

Comment: Add the command you are running to your question. Also post some samples lines (like first 5 or 10) from both files and post your desired output from it.

Comment: Are you specifying `-t ,`?

Comment: How do you know they're sorted? Try `sort -c` on both files.

Answer (score 0):

I´ll mention another answer i found searching for the same problem:

"If you are sure you properly sorted your input files and their lines can be paired, you can avoid the above error by running join --nocheck-order file1.txt file2.txt"

This worked for me. Anyway, there are another answers there.

Thanks to @Yoav Weiss https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12942/join-file-2-not-in-sorted-order